# New GPOs in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I've been looking for this information all over, but I can't find it (and maybe it does not exist)

But I'm looking for a specific list of new GPO in R2 compared to W2008 non-R2.

I don't care about the high-level info, I just need a list of new GPOs.

Thanks x1,000,000
Toast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spreadsheet of all Windows 2008 R2 (and Windows 7) group policies is available on [Microsoft's download site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=18c90c80-8b0a-4906-a4f5-ff24cc2030fb&displaylang=en).

From the 2008 R2 spreadsheet, you can filter the "Supported On" column to only review Windows 7 and 2008 R2 policies.  It looks like there are about 180 additions for these operating systems.